# Automaticaly placing cursor in an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i am making a planning app where people can add and remove tasks. Now i want to add one last function to this app and that is when someone creates a new task. The cursor automaticaly jumps to the beginning of the Task title. This way it will be way more clear for the user that they can edit the text on thier task cards. This action should always trigger when a new task is created and the cursor should always jump to the last task added.

```js
// Add button
const AddToDoButton = document.getElementById('new-to-do');

// Columns
const ToDoColumn = document.getElementById('to-do-column');
const InProgressColumn = document.getElementById('in-progress-column');
const CompleteColumn = document.getElementById('complete-column');

// all columns
const Columns = document.querySelectorAll('.task-column');

// selecting all tasks and initial function call
var Tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task');
NewTasksCheck();

//example task initial function call
AddNewTask();

// ---------------------------
// Add new task structure
// ---------------------------

AddToDoButton.addEventListener('click', AddNewTask);

function AddNewTask(){
  // all HTML task parts
  const NewTaskContainer = document.createElement('div');
  const NewTaskHead = document.createElement('div');
  const NewTaskName = document.createElement('h3');
  const NewTaskDeleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  const NewTaskDescription = document.createElement('p');

  // adding drag
  NewTaskContainer.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');

  // making content editable
  NewTaskName.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
  NewTaskDescription.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');

  // hover change cursor to pointer 
  NewTaskDeleteButton.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    NewTaskDeleteButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  })

  NewTaskName.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    NewTaskName.style.cursor = 'text';
  });

  NewTaskDescription.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    NewTaskDescription.style.cursor = 'text';
  });

  // delete function call 
  NewTaskDeleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    NewTaskContainer.parentNode.removeChild(NewTaskContainer);
  });

  // adding all the classes
  NewTaskContainer.classList.add('task');
  NewTaskHead.classList.add('task-head');
  NewTaskDeleteButton.classList.add('delete-task');
  NewTaskDescription.classList.add('task-description');

  // adding all the content
  NewTaskName.innerHTML = "Your task name";
  NewTaskDescription.innerHTML = "Your description"
  NewTaskDeleteButton.innerHTML = "X"

  // HTML structure
  ToDoColumn.appendChild(NewTaskContainer);
  NewTaskContainer.appendChild(NewTaskHead);
  NewTaskHead.appendChild(NewTaskName);
  NewTaskHead.appendChild(NewTaskDeleteButton);
  NewTaskContainer.appendChild(NewTaskDescription);

  NewTasksCheck();
}

// ---------------------------
// dragable functionality
// ---------------------------

function NewTasksCheck(){
  Tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task');
  Tasks.forEach(draggable => {
    draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
      draggable.classList.add('dragging');
      // console.log("dragstart");
    });
    draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
      draggable.classList.remove('dragging');
      // console.log("dragend");
    });
  });

  Columns.forEach(Column => {
    Column.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging');
      Column.appendChild(draggable);
    });
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

header {
  height: 8vh;
  background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header > h1 {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

main {
  background-color: rgb(206, 234, 243);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;

}

.task-column {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  min-height: fit-content;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.task-column > * {
  margin: 10px;
}

.task {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: move;
}

.task-head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid black 1px;
}

.delete-task {
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.add-to-do {
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  background-color: rgb(140, 233, 2);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: ease-in-out 100ms;
}

.add-to-do:hover {
  transform: scale(110%);
}

.add-to-do:active {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

.task.dragging {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <h1>planning</h1>
    <button id="new-to-do" class="add-to-do">Add To Do</button>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div id="to-do-column" class="task-column">
      <h2>To Do</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="in-progress-column" class="task-column">
      <h2>In Progress</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="complete-column" class="task-column">
      <h2>Complete</h2>
    </div>
  </main>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<!-- example task structure -->

<!-- <div draggable="true" class="task">
  <div class="task-head">
    <h3 contenteditable="true">Task name</h3>
    <button class="delete-task">X</button>
  </div>
  <p contenteditable="true" class="task-description">
    Task description
  </p>
</div> -->
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to scroll down to the last added task?

Comment: No I want the cursor to jump to te task title so people can emediatly edit the task title without having to click on it

Answer (score 2):

You can call [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) after the NewTaskName appended

`NewTaskName.focus();`

Comment: and is there a way to make the placeholder text dissapear when the user starts typing ?

Comment: because you can only use the placeholder attribute on an input tag

Comment: `NewTaskName.innerHTML=""` you also can add blur event listener and set "placeholder" back if innerHTML is empty. However, I would rather suggest to use input instead of h3

Comment: i did it with inputs and it works way easier that way Thanks xD